# Porting a win32 MIDI SysEx application to MacOSX

Tags: macos, winapi, midi, sysex

What is the easiest way to port a win32 MIDI SysEx application (a configuration program), to MacOSX ?

The application itself is written in Qt, but I have no experience in OSX MIDI APIs. Are there good enough drop-in replacements for calls like:

- midiInOpen
- midiOutOpen
- midiOutPrepareHeader
- midiOutLongMsg

and a couple more? Is there a decent source of information for someone who has never programmed under MacOSX to develop MIDI SysEx applications? CoreAudio?

Comment: just wondering which device is missing a management application on the mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a great little (just one .cpp file + headers) midi library - crossplatform and all :)

It's also a great source to analyse and to learn from.. a little nugget in the whole undocumented field.

http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/index.html

Answer (score 2):

What is your development platform? If you're writing a Native Coca Application for the mac, Apple wrote a complete framework to deal with the Midi traffic named CoreMidi. The CoreMidi framework deliver the whole package of midi (include SysEx) and even extend it with network support.

I recommend having a look at [Pete Goodliffe blog post](http://goodliffe.blogspot.com/2010/10/using-coremidi-in-ios-example.html) of using CoreMidi for iOS devices. Although you're not developing for iOS, there is a lot of CoreMidi related information there.

There is a simple, yet brilliant, application that I use a lot on my studio named: [Midi Monitor](http://www.snoize.com/MIDIMonitor/) which is an [open source](https://github.com/krevis/MIDIApps) application. I recommend having a look there too.

Comment: Qt / C++. We are using it for portability to Linux, MacOSX and Win32. The Midi component, while critical, is not real-time and not a major part of the code (at least in terms of lines of code). Thus, unless bridging Cocoa/C++ is trivial, we'd stick with native code. (Yes, I know nothing about Apple's platform, or even what goes where).